# C: string to milisecs timestamp

Tags: c, redis, timestamp, time-t

I want return in a function a time_t value from timestamp in string format but i don't get it. I need help.

I read a string KEY of a Redis database that it is a timestamp value with form, for example, "1456242904.226683"

My code is:

```
time_t get_ts(redisContext *ctx)
{
    redisReply *reply;
    reply = redisCommand(ctx, "GET %s", "KEY");
    if(reply == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    char error[255];
    sprintf(error, "%s", "get_ts 2:",reply->str);
    send_log(error);

    freeReplyObject(reply);

    return reply->str;
}
```

reply->str is a string value but i need return a time_t value.

How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: after `freeReplyObject()`, you cannot `return` a member anyway....

Comment: Right @sourav-ghosh. Ooops! Sorry. I tried to resume my question.  ô_Ô

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that 1456242904.226683 are the seconds past since 00:00, Jan 1 1970. This would be about 46 years.
1456242904.226683 is a floating point value and `time_t` is a integral data type.
You can't convert 1456242904.226683 to `time_t` exactly, but you can convert 1456242904.
First Use `atof` to convert a string to an floting point value,
then cast the floating point value to `time_t`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>     // atof

time_t get_ts(redisContext *ctx)
{
    redisReply *reply;
    reply = redisCommand(ctx, "GET %s", "KEY");
    if(reply == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    char error[255];
    sprintf(error, "%s", "get_ts 2:",reply->str);
    send_log(error);

    time_t t = (time_t)atof(reply->str);
             // ^^^^^^ ^^^^

    freeReplyObject(reply);

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Rabbid, your solution is almost perfect :)

My reply->str variable is in the form 1456242904.226683 but (time_t) atof(reply->str) return only 1456242904

I dont understand that. What is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: @Lamujeresponja It is as I tried to explane in my answer. `time_t` is an integral data type. It can't hold the digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Yes, sorry. My english is poor. And then, now i have find a solution to get milisecs conversion.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards from Spain.
Elvira